# Xcode 7 update completes but Xcode 6.4 remains

Tags: xcode, software-update

I updated Xcode but it doesn't appear to have actually updated. This is seen in my update history after reboot:

[image]

I click that and I get a link to Open the application.

[image]

I click that and I open a version that reports it is 6.4

[image]

Is anyone else having this problem, or does anyone know what I'm not doing correctly to apply the update?

Comment: I got the same problem, is it possible to fix it without reinstall ?

Comment: @Chlebta not that I've discovered and not that anyone else has revealed. Once I fixed mine I stopped bothering with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode installed correctly after moving it out of the Applications folder and into the Trash. I reinstalled from the App store and now the correct version number is showing.